# Inserting a background banner

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using [UI Semantic](http://semantic-ui.com/) for the first time. I'm using the starter theme as given on the official example website: http://semantic-ui.com/examples/homepage.html

I'm trying to display a background-image in the banner, so I checked where the dark background is applied:

```
<div class="ui inverted banner-bg vertical masthead center aligned segment ">..</div>
```

I added the class `banner-bg` in order to apply a background-image, but it doesn't taking effect.
This is my class:

```
  .banner-bg{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    background-image: url(../../images/banner_1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: What is happening, exactly? The image isn't being applied? Is the `color` property applied to the text inside the banner? If so, your rule is being applied, and it's likely that the `../../images/banner_1.jpg` file is inaccessible to the browser.

Comment: The path is correct, is like the class is not overwriting the div classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it isn't applied is because the CSS uses the statements in the most specific declared block.

The Theme declares the background over the following statement:

```
.ui.inverted.segment, .ui.primary.inverted.segment {
    background: #1B1C1D;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

So `.ui.inverted.segment` is more specific than your `.banner-bg`.
How to override this?

You just need to declare it more specific like `.ui.inverted.segment.banner-bg`

---

To visualize this, i made a short [CodePen-Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBNyRJ)
I'll post the demo code also here do describe the solution:

```css
.first.second.third{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.first.second.third.bg-banner{
  background: red;
}
.bg-banner{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first second third and so on">Test</div>
<div class="first second third and so on bg-banner">Test 2</div>
```

So the background is red, even your `green` statement comes later. If you add the exact same classes like in the statement above, the background gets green.

A very detailed article about this topic have CSS-Tricks: [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

give him specific height

```
.banner-bg{
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
background-image: url(../../images/banner_1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px(as your image size)

}
```

Comment: That is not the issue, the problem is that class is not overwriting the other classes

Answer (score 0):

The selector is there for you already. You don't have to add any class.
Just do this:

```
.ui.inverted.segment, .ui.primary.inverted.segment {
    background: #1B1C1D;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/wisdomabioye/image/upload/v1462961781/about_vbxvdi.jpg');
}
```

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but is not good practice overwriting the styles, is better to create a new class and then apply it, but thanks anyway ;)